# Find a data-attribute in test with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Trying to figure out with shallowMount how I can find a data attribute and check if that attribute is there in the Vue template:

**myVue.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div data-test="apple"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "fruit-main",
    extends: registerStore(),
    components: {

    },
    props: {

    },
    data() {

    },
    mounted() {

    },
    computed: {

    },
    methods: {

    },
    watch: {

    }
}
</script>
```

**spec.js** (using Vue Test Utils and mocha):

```
it('shows an apple', () => {
  let fakeStore = new Vuex.Store({ state: {} });
  const apple = shallowMount(myVue, {fakeStore}),

  expect(apple).to.have.length(1);
});
```

**OR maybe this way???**

**myVue.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div apple></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**spec.js**

```
it('shows an apple', () => {
  const vue = shallowMount(myVue),
    apple = vue.element.getAttribute('apple')

  expect(apple).to.exist
// or expect(apple).to.have.length(1); - which is how you'd do it with enzyme but I'm not sure yet what getAttribute returns yet
});
```

but I'm not sure how to go about it, obviously this is not right.  I'm an enzyme and React guy trying to figure out how to do the same kinds of tests with Vue basically.

**Note**: I use shallowMount solely for TDD I am not interested in mount() and I'm not about to debate that right now for this post.  I'm just asking help for shallowMount here and how to find a a data-attribute for my tests to assert on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use wrapper [attributes()](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#attributes) assuming the dataset is in the wrapper itself.

ie.

```
import FruitMain from '@components/FruitMain.vue'
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'

describe('@components/FruitMain.vue', () => {
  it('shows an apple', () => {
    // We are assuming the FruitMain component receives a 'fruit' prop.
    const wrapper = shallowMount(FruitMain, { propsData: { fruit: 'apple' } })

    // Has the correct starting data fruit
    expect(wrapper.attributes()['data-fruit']).toBe('apple')

    // Has the correct fruit value when props change
    // wrapper.setProps({ fruit: 'banana' })
    // expect(wrapper.attributes()['data-fruit']).toBe('banana')
  })
})
```

---

To search for a child that has a dataset use [contains()](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#contains-selector).

```
import FruitMain from '@components/FruitMain.vue'
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'

describe('@components/FruitMain.vue', () => {
  it('shows an apple', () => {
    // We are assuming the FruitMain component receives a 'fruit' prop.
    const wrapper = shallowMount(FruitMain, { propsData: { fruit: 'apple' } })

    // Has a data fruit
    expect(wrapper.contains('[data-fruit]')).toBe(true) // or [data-fruit="apple"]
  })
})
```

### [CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zxqo9rw46l?previewwindow=tests)

Comment: What if I just want to find an element by its data attribute name?  I don’t need to set the data attribute value, I just need to find a part of the template, that DOM element by a certain attribute name...that simple

Comment: I’ve never needed a test marker based on an attribute to have a value for the attribute simply just give me the element by finding the element that has that data attribute I am trying to find.  The data attribute name -is- the selector I want to find by

Comment: I just want to check that the element exists and that’s it right now

Comment: You can use [`contains()`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#contains-selector) and pass `[data-fruit]` as a selector.

Comment: @PositiveGuy I included a CodeSandbox demo which you can also use for future issues / questions regarding `vue-test-utils`, might come in handy `:)`.